# iOS UIImageView doesn't show anything on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I have a scrollViewController, in viewDidLoad, I add an UIImageView to it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
}
```

Then I set my image:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
    self.imageView.image = image;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image ? self.image.size : CGSizeZero;
}
```

On iPhone, this works fine, but on iPad (SplitViewController Detail), it doesn't show anything.
I think the problem is, that on iPhone ViewDidLoad is called when there is already an image set, on iPad when the app launches, the detail is always on screen.

I tried to put the addSubview to setImage, this works, but when the user clicks another item, the two imageViewControllers overlay each other.

Could anyone help me? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Your presumption seems right. Why don't you just add one UIImageView to your View using interfaceBuilder?

Comment: I follow a Tutorial to learn Objective C, they added the view programmatically to show the different ways to add a view.
However, I tried your tip now, but the problem is still there :(

Comment: OK I'll explain it in a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding second imageViewController, you should remove first imageViewController

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//_imageView variable is created by outlet, or you can do it by programmatically
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];
}

- (void) setNewImage
{
[_imageView removeFromSuperview];
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basics:

- `viewDidLoad` is only called once the controller is loaded into memory. So in your `SplitViewController` the `viewDidLoad` method is invoked immediately after launching the app.

My suggestion:

Add a `UIImageView` from InterfaceBuilder and connect it to your controller using a `IBOutlet`. This is the easiest way to reach the goal. I assume you're using a storyboard?!

right click drag the outlet to your header:
[image: right click drag the outlet to your header]

enter a name for your property and click connect
[image]

This way you can access your `UIImageView` in your implementation and you're good to go. No need to add it programmatically.

For further informations have a look at this tutorial: http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-A-Beginners-Guide-to-Storyboard-Connection

Comment: I followed your instructions exactly, it didn't solve the actual problem, but it's much easier this way, thank you!